# ms-word 2002/2003, how to shrink the size of comment balloons

Tags: microsoft-word, comments, microsoft-word-2002

I often have a lot of comments in some of my ms-Word 2002/2003 files and I would like to be able to see all the comments of a given page visible all at once. But when the number of comments goes beyond a certain limit, say 22 or 25 or more, all comments beyond the 22th are not visible on the right margin (already wide enough) and the rest becomes only visible at the bottom of the page. I would like to be able to shrink the height size of the comment balloons so that I could see the 25 or more comments, even if not in full text in each. Is it feasible with a VBA macro ?

Comment: [Enlarge the Tiny Text in the Comment and Track Changes Balloon Text](https://www.journalofaccountancy.com/issues/2002/aug/enlargethetinytextinthecommentandtrackchangesballoontext.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer.  It handles pretty well what I was looking for.  There is still the point of reducing the comment balloon rounded rectangle.  I mean certain comments have just a word in it with bigger balloon height than others which have two lines in them for instance.  Is there a way to shrink that height ?

Comment: No idea........